# Not able to change font HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

For some reason, I am unable to change the font of any of my text on the website. I have a feeling something in one of the CSS files is overriding this. Here are some of my CSS files:

Style:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,900");
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");

/* Basic */


body, input, select, textarea {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}

body {
}

    body.loading * {
        -moz-animation: none !important;
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        -o-animation: none !important;
        -ms-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
    }

a {
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    a:hover {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```

/* Icon */

```
    .icon:before {
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: none !important;
    }

    .icon > .label {
        display: none;
    }

/* Wrapper */
    @-moz-keyframes wrapper { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes wrapper { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-o-keyframes wrapper { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-ms-keyframes wrapper { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @keyframes wrapper { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
```

/* BG */

```
/* Overlay */
    @-moz-keyframes overlay { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes overlay { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-o-keyframes overlay { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @-ms-keyframes overlay { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
    @keyframes overlay { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }

    #overlay {
        -moz-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
        -webkit-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
        -o-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
        -ms-animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
        animation: overlay 1.5s 1.5s forwards;
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
        background-image: url("images/overlay-pattern.png"), url("images/bg.jpg");
        background-position: top left, center center;
        background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: auto, cover;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

/* Main */

    #main {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        font-family: "Times New Roman";
        width: 100%;
    }

        #main:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            margin-right: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 1px;
        }

/* Header */
    @-moz-keyframes header { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes header { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-o-keyframes header { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-ms-keyframes header { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @keyframes header { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-moz-keyframes nav-icons { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes nav-icons { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-o-keyframes nav-icons { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @-ms-keyframes nav-icons { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }
    @keyframes nav-icons { 0% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); transform: translate3d(0,1em,0); opacity: 0; } 100% { -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); opacity: 1; } }



#header {
        -moz-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
        -webkit-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
        -o-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
        -ms-animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
        animation: header 1s 2.25s forwards;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        cursor: default;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 0;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        top: -1em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 90%;
    }

        #header h1 {
            font-size: 4.35em;
            font-weight: 900;
            letter-spacing: -0.035em;
            line-height: 1em;
        }

    #FirstP{
        margin-top: -120px;
        font-size: 10px;

    }
    #Noah{
        margin-right: 700px;
        font-size: 10px;

    }
    #ThirdP{
        margin-left: 700px;
        margin-top: -120px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    #FourthP{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    #FifthP{
        margin-left:700px;
        margin-top: -125px;
        font-size: 10px

    }
    #SixthP{
        margin-right: 700px;
        margin-top: -115px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }




    #header p {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        margin: 0.75em 0 0.25em 0;
        opacity: 0.75;
    }

    #header nav {
        margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
    }

            #header nav li:nth-child(1) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 2.5s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
                -o-animation-delay: 2.5s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
                animation-delay: 2.5s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(2) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 2.75s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 2.75s;
                -o-animation-delay: 2.75s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 2.75s;
                animation-delay: 2.75s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(3) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
                -o-animation-delay: 3s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
                animation-delay: 3s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(4) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 3.25s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 3.25s;
                -o-animation-delay: 3.25s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 3.25s;
                animation-delay: 3.25s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(5) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
                -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 3.5s;
                animation-delay: 3.5s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(6) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 3.75s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 3.75s;
                -o-animation-delay: 3.75s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 3.75s;
                animation-delay: 3.75s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(7) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
                -o-animation-delay: 4s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
                animation-delay: 4s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(8) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 4.25s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 4.25s;
                -o-animation-delay: 4.25s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 4.25s;
                animation-delay: 4.25s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(9) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 4.5s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
                -o-animation-delay: 4.5s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
                animation-delay: 4.5s;
            }

            #header nav li:nth-child(10) {
                -moz-animation-delay: 4.75s;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 4.75s;
                -o-animation-delay: 4.75s;
                -ms-animation-delay: 4.75s;
                animation-delay: 4.75s;
            }

        #header nav a {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            border: 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }

            #header nav a:before {
                -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                border-radius: 100%;
                border: solid 1px white;
                display: block;
                font-size: 1.75em;
                height: 2.5em;
                line-height: 2.5em;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                top: 0;
                width: 2.5em;
            }



                #header nav a:hover:before {
                    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.175);
                    color: white;
                }

            #header nav a:active {
                font-size: 0.95em;
                background: none;
            }

                #header nav a:active:before {
                    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
                    color: white;
                }

            #header nav a span {
                display: none;
            }

#footer {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%);
    cursor: default;
    height: 6em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 8em;
    width: 100%;
}`
```

Comment: I can't seem to be able to even add <b> or <i> tags anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your text is inside the #main div hence getting the times new roman font? Hard to tell without the markup but it does'nt seem like there's an error with font import-

Tried with the top part of your css to set font to source sans pro like so:

```
p {
  font-family:'source sans pro'
}
```

which seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/61uzrL80/

Comment: Try to recreate the problem in a jsfiddle for us to be able to help you, need to look at how the markup is structured.

Comment: There is about 5 or 6 different CSS files, 3 JS and 1 HTML page. Maybe I can upload the CSS folder if that's okay?

Comment: If you post a jsfiddle of your problem I may be able to look at it, you need to do some research of your own if you expect someone to help you.

Comment: When pasting in my code into jsfiddle it does not show the page correctly. Also, I've been spending loads of time on my own already. And tried getting the font problem fixed for quite a lot of time before I decided to come onto Stack Overflow

Comment: Well, I guess you've tried using web tools to inspect elements. There you can tell if and from where the font-family property get overriden